# JS how to create a break point programmatically

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

Using any JS dev tools is there a way to programmatically create a debugger break point? I'm using chrome, but don't mind to switch to a different environment supporting the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It never was so simple. Anywhere you want in JS place the statement:

```
debugger;
```

If the Chrome debugger is open, it will break there.

Answer (score 0):

Use alert() , that should do the trick.

Comment: What part of "programmatically" did you misunderstand?

Comment: can I get access to the context vars, which is the most interesting part, I know that the line I'm trying to debug gets hit.